# Hiberante Lucene Hangs while calling startAndWait()

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I am using hibernate lucene search(4.5.1) in my application in the cloud environment. For each tenant a separate hibernate configuration is maintained (all the properties are same except `hibernate.search.default.indexBase` property. Each tenant has separate filesystem location). While starting the application I made the logic to index some table data by unique location for each tenant (eg: d:/dbindex/tenant1/, d:/dbindex/tenant2/) by calling the method `Search.getFullTextSession(session).createIndexer().startAndWait()`. For the first tenant every thing is fine, index was perfectly done. For the second tenant the startAndWait is not completed. It doesn't comes out from the `startAndWait()` but some time it is working. Some time doesn't comes out from the `startAndWait()`. After a serious debugging I found that `BatchIndexingWorkspace` has two thread producer and consumer where producer take the list of Id from DB and put it in queue and Consumer takes and indexes it. At the producer side (IdentifierProducer) a method named `inTransactionWrapper` has a statement

```
Transaction transaction = Helper.getTransactionAndMarkForJoin( session );
transaction.begin();
```

The statement `transaction.begin()` gets hangs and transaction doesn't begins so producer is not produced so consumer didn't indexed and startAndWait freezes. After a long search some post says that pool size will make a dead lock. But I am using `BoneCPConnectionProvider` with `maxConnectionsPerPartition` with 50 (per tenant). I monitored the active connection while starting, it doesn't exceed 10. More connection are available. But I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Have you considered dynamic sharding - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#advanced-features-dynamic-sharding - to separate the indexes. The use case you are describing is one of the use cases this feature was created. I am not sure whether you approach works at all. You would have to share your configuration as well as bootstrap and index code. Are you bootstrapping multiple SearchFactories? Or how else would you change the index base? How do you want to handle all this when it comes to index updates during runtime?

Comment: @Hardy Yes of-course hardy it is also one of the solution but I had proceed with the former one (In the question) because I am having separate session for each tenant so it is easy to handle in that way. Even my former one works for some time. I think it is some other problem. I couldn't able to identify it. It May be DB connection pool size issue but still more connections are available. So what else??